# Laravel 5.8: How to check data type in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Controller with a method like this

```
public function chargeWallet(Request $request, $wallet, $user)
    {
        try {
            $data = $request->validate([
               'charge' => 'required|integer',
            ]);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
        return redirect(back());
    }
```

As you can see I'm checking that the `charge` type must be **integer**.

Now I want to check if the data type of `charge` was integer, then do this:

```
if($data['charge'] == INTEGER)
   flash()->overlay('Success!', 'Success Message', 'success');
```

So the question is, how to check the type of data in the Controller ? What should I write instead of `INTEGER` for checking `$data['charge']` ?

Comment: You're already checking that `charge` is an integer in `validate()`, `$data['charge']` will be an integer or a 422 will be throw

Comment: @JuanEizmendi This was an example and a different question. Just wanna know how to check this data type in Controller

Comment: `is_int($var)` [is_int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `is_int($var)` or `is_integer($var)`. you can also use `is_numeric($var)` to check if the variable is a number or a numeric string.

```
if(is_int($data['charge']))
   flash()->overlay('Success!', 'Success Message', 'success');
```